# How to dynamically set the height on just one header row in ag-grid for react

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

This method sets the height

```
gridApi.setHeaderHeight(height);
```

But the problem is it sets height for both header groups.

```
 (Header group spans entire width)<------------------------- height gets set here
                                                            
(Header1    | Header 2   | header 3)<------------------------ and height gets set here
------------------------------------
row data 1 | row data 2 | row data 3
```

How to set the height for just one header row

```
 (Header group spans entire width)
                                                            
(Header1    | Header 2   | header 3)<------------------------ This row one only
------------------------------------
row data 1 | row data 2 | row data 3
```

See example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-practice-forked-py43m?file=/src/index.tsx

Click Expand, and see both column header groups expand in height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I've come up with a solution to circumvent this.

**Simpler version:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-custom-setaddedcolheight-sypg2?file=/src/Grid/Columns.tsx

**More dynamic version:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-custom-setaddedcolheight-expand-reduce-mh8rw?file=/src/Grid/Columns.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is impossible. The following methods can be used, but they set the height for the entire line in the header. I think this is a rather strange design decision to increase the header for only one of the columns.

```
gridApi.setHeaderHeight(value) 
gridApi.setGroupHeaderHeight(value)
```

Comment: It's not a single column I want to set the height on. Its the row. The problem is if I use setHeaderHeight it sets the height on all header groups. Updated my question for clarity

Comment: Do you using this code for groups and the columns?
 <AgGridReact>
  <AgGridColumn field="Header 1">
    <AgGridColumn field="extra header" />
  </AgGridColumn >
  <AgGridColumn field="Header 2">
    <AgGridColumn field="extra header" />
  </AgGridColumn>
</AgGridReact>

Comment: if so then try to use code from my previous answer. Create customHeaderGroupComponent. Then to change the height of the group use the method gridApi.setGroupHeaderHeight(value) and to change the height of the column header use the method gridApi.setHeaderHeight(value)

Comment: ok I've added an example - see - https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-practice-forked-py43m?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: I looked at your example, you are right, it really is. Then I went to the official site of ag grid and checked it out there. It doesn't work for them either. https://ag-grid.com/react-grid/column-headers/#dynamic-header-heights
setGroupHeaderHeight set height only for a group, but setHeaderHeight set height for a group and column header.